# translate en.html to fr.html, de.html... etc

Tags: html, internationalization

I have a landing page, static html, in english language. (home.en.html)

I try to find a tool that it can translate english to other lang in the world.

I hope a CLI tool can do this:

```
translate-tool 'home.en.html' 'home.de.html'
translate-tool 'home.en.html' 'home.fr.html'
...
every lang in the world!
```

So every lang has a landing page in their own lang.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way , you may try the solution provided by Hussein - https://stackoverflow.com/users/560735/hussein

```
google.load("language", "1");

function initialize() {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    content.innerHTML = '<div id="text">Hola, me alegro mucho de verte.<\/div><div id="translation"/>';
    var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    google.language.translate(text, 'es', 'en', function(result) {
        var translated = document.getElementById("translation");
        if (result.translation) {
            translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

you may try his JSFiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/wJ2QP/1/